# Calculating $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{X}} \mathbb{u}^{T}\boldsymbol{X}\mathbb{u}$ with symmetric $\boldsymbol{X}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

We want to calculate $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{X}} \mathbb{u}^{T}\boldsymbol{X}\mathbb{u}$ with $\boldsymbol{X}$ being a symmetric matrix.

Let $\circ$ denote the Hadamard product for vectors.
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{X}} \mathbb{u}^{T}\boldsymbol{X}\mathbb{u} =
&\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{i j}} \sum_{p, q} u_{p} X_{p q} u_{q}=\sum_{p, q} u_{p}
\frac{\partial X_{p q}}{\partial X_{i j}} u_{q}
\end{align*}

Now, let's analyze $\frac{\partial X_{p q}}{\partial X_{i j}}$. This becomes $1$ for both $p=i \land q=j$ and for $q=i \land p=j$ since $\mathbb{\boldsymbol{X}}=\mathbb{\boldsymbol{X}}^{\top} \iff X_{i j} = X_{j i}$, thus we will get 2 different Kronecker deltas for each case  $\delta_{p i}\delta_{q j}$ and $\delta_{q i}\delta_{p j}$ respectively.

This will yield us for $i\neq j$:
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{p, q} u_{p}\frac{\partial X_{p q}}{\partial X_{i j}} u_{q} = \sum_{p, q} u_{p}u_{q} \delta_{p i}\delta_{q j} + u_{p}u_{q} \delta_{q i}\delta_{p j} = 2\mathbb{u}\mathbb{u}^{\top}
\end{align*}

For the diagonal terms we will just get $\mathbb{u}$'s elements squared since for $i=j$:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{p, q} u_{p}\frac{\partial X_{p q}}{\partial X_{i i}} u_{q} = \sum_{p, q} u_{p}u_{q} \delta_{p i}\delta_{q i} = u_i u_i = \mathbb{u} \circ \mathbb{u}
\end{align*}

Thus combining this we get the final result by subtracting the squared elements from the diagonal once:
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{X}} \mathbb{u}^{T}\boldsymbol{X}\mathbb{u} = 2\mathbb{u}\mathbb{u}^\top - \operatorname{diag}(\mathbb{u}\circ\mathbb{u})
\end{align*}

I know this contradicts the known result $\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{a}^{\top} \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{b}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}=\boldsymbol{a b}^{\top}$ so what did I miss?

Comment: I think that $\partial X_{pq}/\partial X_{ij}=\delta_{pq}{}^{ij}$, which simplifies the subsequent computations quite a little bit.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro can you explain your notation?

Comment: Right, it is better written this way; $\partial X_{pq}/\partial X_{ij}=\delta_p{}^i \delta_q{}^j$.

Answer (score 1):

That known result is for non-symmetric matrices. Basically, the way you defined your derivative with the symmetric matrix, to have the derivatives repeated in the lower and upper triangular part of the matrix, the correct answer would be
$\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{a}^{\top} \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{b}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}}=\boldsymbol{a b}^{\top} + \boldsymbol{b a}^{\top} - \operatorname{diag}(\mathbb{a}\circ\mathbb{b})$

By repeated derivatives, I mean that if $i\neq j$ the derivative $\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{a}^{\top} \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{b}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}_{ij}} = \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{a}^{\top} \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{b}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}_{ji}}$ appears twice, while if $i=j$ the derivative $\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{a}^{\top} \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{b}}{\partial \boldsymbol{X}_{ii}}$ appears only once.

Comment: Are there any other constraints for the known result? I.e. non-diagonal, non-toeplitz etc?

Comment: It's just for a regular matrix $X$ with $n \times n$ different entries. If you add dependence between the entries (like for symmetric) you usually get different things. A good way to think about this, if you are familiar with machine learning, is using backpropagation (which is just the chain rule anyways). The derivative for a general matrix is the formula you wrote, then when you backpropagate this derivative from a general matrix to it's symmetric counterpart, you are taking the first derivative, and on the off-diagonals you add the transpose, but keep it the same in the diagonals.

Comment: [Some](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.06491.pdf) would argue that the symmetric gradient is actually $\,\frac 12(ab^T+ba^T)\;$